# create shape not working in laravel (imagecreatetruecolor )

Tags: php, laravel, shapes

I am trying to create few shapes like circle, rectangle in PHP laravel. My program working fine in a normal PHP file. But whenever I am trying to add this code in laravel its returns a special character.

> geometric.blade.php

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png");
// Create a 200 x 200 image
$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 200);

// Allocate colors
$pink = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 255, 105, 180);
$white = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 255, 255, 255);
$green = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 132, 135, 28);

// Draw three rectangles each with its own color
imagerectangle($canvas, 50, 50, 150, 150, $pink);
imagerectangle($canvas, 45, 60, 120, 100, $white);
imagerectangle($canvas, 100, 120, 75, 160, $green);

// Output and free from memory
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

imagejpeg($canvas);
imagedestroy($canvas);
?>
```

> Error output in laravel

```
����JFIF``��>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v90), default quality ��C    $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342��C  2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222����"�� ���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������� ���w!1AQaq"2�B���� #3R�br� $4�%�&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������?���(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��+cA�l�5�翽�����\�Al'v̱�)te9�@�[+ 7L'I����ݥ�I�l��H��"�aGj��V���o����㵻�ZxL�h���h(�m�iG�/'�'���s���c��u��C��T�6��v^]e�S�ճ����.?��ڶ��������c��u��C��T}�����?�M�%Qr}����ȧ��g�@ 7��\��?�l�����ˏ�;W>������&��������;����J���e�%�E?�[?�i���������g�@ 7��\�ڹ�?��w\��4?��G���A�s����Uk/�/�)�j���M����v��[?�i�������ϱ�?����� �����t��O�zO��}��[o7n����d�8�2h�{YI�'����4���q��h�ճ����.?��e�E����K��� �u��m�/�[�H��r�D�n���:���M�B2�ו����Yt1�� �?
```

Please let me know how to run this in Laravel framework. Thanks!

Comment: are you setting this header in laravel on request object?

Comment: like this: `request()->headers->set('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg')` before sending the response

Answer (score 0):

You can not use header on blade/view. You should create it on controller/route directly.

example on route:

```
Route::get(
    '/test/img',
    function () {

header("Content-type: image/png");
// Create a 200 x 200 image
$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 200);

// Allocate colors
$pink = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 255, 105, 180);
$white = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 255, 255, 255);
$green = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 132, 135, 28);

// Draw three rectangles each with its own color
imagerectangle($canvas, 50, 50, 150, 150, $pink);
imagerectangle($canvas, 45, 60, 120, 100, $white);
imagerectangle($canvas, 100, 120, 75, 160, $green);

// Output and free from memory
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

imagejpeg($canvas);
imagedestroy($canvas);

    }
);
```

Content-type header in view/blade will be replaced by default. But if you still want use blade actually you can use `die` function in the end of blade file.

Example on blade

```
<?php

    header("Content-type: image/png");
// Create a 200 x 200 image
$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 200);

// Allocate colors
$pink = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 255, 105, 180);
$white = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 255, 255, 255);
$green = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 132, 135, 28);

// Draw three rectangles each with its own color
imagerectangle($canvas, 50, 50, 150, 150, $pink);
imagerectangle($canvas, 45, 60, 120, 100, $white);
imagerectangle($canvas, 100, 120, 75, 160, $green);

// Output and free from memory
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

imagejpeg($canvas);
imagedestroy($canvas);

die;
```